# Add missing file after remove all file older 90 days

Tags: yum, system-recovery

I'm facing a big problem wity my server, running centos 5.x
 Last day, i write a command to delete all old log files:

```
LOG_FOLDER= /var/spool/asterisk/backup
find $LOG_FOLDER/* -mtime +90 -delete
```

This command was fine.
 I copy it to script and run maybe my mistake when didn't check syntax of script before run. All files in my server older than 90 days was deleted.
 All bash file was broken ( yum, rpm, sh, bash ,...)
 I tried copy file from other machine, and i receive a message:

```
-bash: /bin/sh: Permission denied
```

I used vncviewer to edit permission:

```
 [root@log]# bash
-bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
```

Yum command :

```
[root@log]# yum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 4, in ?
    import yum
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 44, in ?
    import rpmsack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 22, in ?
    import misc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 14, in ?
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/tempfile.py", line 33, in ?
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/random.py", line 828, in ?
    _inst = Random()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/random.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.seed(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/random.py", line 109, in seed
    a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/urandom'
```

My server don't any backup file :(. 
 Anyone can help me pls :(

Comment: You shouldn't have a space in `LOG_FOLDER= /var/spool/asterisk/backup`. Terrible, maybe you can mount the drive ti other system and backup current files before reinstalling everything. Good luck!

Comment: I guess I can add `find / -delete` to my list of _no not ever run_ commands.

Comment: You've deleted most system files. Lesson for the future: don't run dangerous jobs (such as deleting files) as root. Always run tools with the minimum permission they need to do their jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to reinstall almost everything, as you blew away *all* old files, including most of the installed system (i.e., everything that wasn't recently updated).

Congratulations, this is part of the hazing new Unix/Linux users/administrators go through. You are now a full member of the club. It's to always remember Unix hands you more than enough rope to shoot your feet.

Probably the best bet is to ***extremely carefully*** reinstall the system from scratch. Tell it you *don't* want to format the partition containing local data (e.g. `/home`, perhaps others). Back up (from rescue/install media) *all* you can. Best would be to get e.g. an external disk box and a new disk, install the new disk and install on it, and restore from the (now external) original disk.